# How to solve windows AppCertKit failure Direct3D level support

Tags: windows-runtime

I have written a simple Windows App Store application. It is based on VS2013 default template for StoreApps. The UI is only simple textboxes and buttons.

Running the AppCertKit before uploading the App,,, I have a failure. The error message is:

```
Error Found: The Direct3D feature level support test detected the following errors:
   Application App was not running at the end of the test. It likely crashed or was terminated for having become unresponsive.
```

I have no idea what is going on here. Can anybody help me?